# Connecting a MySQL database to Apache Superset

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, mamp, apache-superset

I am trying to connect a MySQL database to Apache Superset but the following error is reported:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'supersetuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I am using MAMP with MySQL running locally on port 8889. I am trying to connect database `apache_superset` using the credentials of user `supersetuser`.
The `SQLAlchemy` URI I am trying to pass in Apache Superset looks like the one below:

```
mysql://supersetuser:superset@localhost:8889/apache_superset
```

I am quite sure that the credentials are correct since I have just created them. 
Furthermore, I have also tried to assign the required privileges to the user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `apache_superset`.* TO 'supersetuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but I am still unable to connect the db to Apache Superset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the solution by replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`

So the complete SQLAlchemy URI becomes:

```
mysql://supersetuser:superset@127.0.0.1:8889/apache_superset
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html#idm140235558252992):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a
> way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
> network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs
> attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file.
> This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port
> number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the
> local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of
> 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server.